# Issue in Running GRID by TheGuardian

Tags: scala, playframework

I have followed all the instructions from docs for running [GRID](https://github.com/guardian/grid) and here is what my [/etc/gu](https://github.com/cstrd/etc-gu) contains. 
and I have created pan-domain-auth bucket in s3 and here are the files in it [file1](https://pan-domain-auth.s3.amazonaws.com/grid.local.public) 
[file2](https://pan-domain-auth.s3.amazonaws.com/grid.local.settings) These files were generated by cognito stack in other s3 buckets using this command ./cognito/generate-settings.sh ${CLOUDFORMATION_STACK} ${REGION}

Also I have added, `libraryDependencies += "com.gu" %% "pan-domain-auth-verification" % "0.2.13";` line to build.sbt in grid.
and in the Cognito config,

I put CALLBACK URL as `http://localhost`
I have done till 3rd step from the [docs](https://github.com/guardian/grid/tree/master/docs).
Here is what I get when I run ./dev-start.sh and go to localhost:9002

> `IllegalStateException: Unable to download public key
>
> No source available, here is the exception stack trace:
>   ->java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to download public key
>        com.gu.pandomainauth.Settings$.errorToThrowable(Settings.scala:55)
>        com.gu.pandomainauth.PanDomainAuthSettingsRefresher.(PanDomainAuthSettingsRefresher.scala:35)
>        com.gu.mediaservice.lib.auth.Authentication.buildPandaSettings(Authentication.scala:85)
>        com.gu.mediaservice.lib.auth.Authentication.panDomainSettings$lzycompute(Authentication.scala:43)
>        com.gu.mediaservice.lib.auth.Authentication.panDomainSettings(Authentication.scala:43)
>        com.gu.pandomainauth.action.AuthActions.settings(Actions.scala:26)
>        com.gu.pandomainauth.action.AuthActions.$init$(Actions.scala:71)
>        com.gu.mediaservice.lib.auth.Authentication.(Authentication.scala:26)
>        com.gu.mediaservice.lib.play.GridComponents.(GridComponents.scala:35)
>        ThrallComponents.(ThrallComponents.scala:8)
>        AppLoader$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(AppLoader.scala:3)
>        AppLoader$$anonfun$$lessinit$greater$1.apply(AppLoader.scala:3)
>        com.gu.mediaservice.lib.play.GridAppLoader.load(GridAppLoader.scala:11)
>        play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$3(DevServerStart.scala:174)
>        play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
>        play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:171)
>        play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:124)
>        play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:241)
>        play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:138)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsyncUnordered$$anon$26.onPush(Ops.scala:1304)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:519)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:482)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
>        akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
>        akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
>        akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:670)
>        akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
>        akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
>        akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
>        akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
>        akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
>        akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>        akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>        akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>        akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)`

Can you look into it, what am I  missing.
Thanks